# Firebase - cordova redirect to blank screen on Ios

Tags: firebase, cordova, firebase-authentication

I have cordova app (no ionic) and I am trying to implement authentication but I get a blank screen in the redirect.

I follow the instruction from here
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova

snippet of my call

```
 var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

 firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider).then(function () {
    return firebase.auth().getRedirectResult();
 }).then(function (result) {


  var token = result.credential.accessToken;
  // The signed-in user info.
  var user = result.user;

  }).catch(function (error) {

   var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
  });
```

Basically , this is what I am seeing

1. My link redirect to the screen to choose my account
2. select the user and login
3. I am forwarded to a screen myprojectname.firebaseapp.com and then it immediately redirect to a blank screen "about:blank"

This is happening on my iOS device

Can you please give some hints on how to fix this  issue

Comment: +1 on this.  It doesn't happen on my app until I put it into Testflight and distribute to testers.  Running locally it never happens.  I have a feeling it has to do with the universal links plugin fix, but since I can't debug on a TestFlight distributed app, I'm somewhat stuck and afraid to release my app.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling background mode helped us resolve the issue. Referenced the link below

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2103